# Remove special characters from a specific JSON object in JSON payload

Tags: javascript, json

I have a large JSON payload and I want to format, the specific object of the payload using JS. 
I want `flightdetails` array object to edit and remove the special characters from it. How can I achieve this?


I have been working on this using XSLT for the past 2 days, and I went nowhere hence I decided to remove it using JS.

**Example of the array**(there can be more than 30 records inside the `flightdetails`)

```
"flightdetails": [
    {
        "id": XF-2092,
        "trips": 2,
        "categories": {
            "flights": [
                "\"return\",\"oneway\""
            ]
        },
        "id": XF-2093,
        "trips": 1,
        "categories": {
            "flights": [
                "\"return\""
            ]
        }
    }
 ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
"flightdetails": [
    {
        "id": XF-2092,
        "trips": 2,
        "categories": {
            "flights": [
                "return","oneway"
            ]
        },
        "id": XF-2093,
        "trips": 1,
        "categories": {
            "flights": [
                "return"
            ]
        }
    }
 ]
```

The flightdetails object inside the `//destinations/flightdetails` path